# Java SSO framework for non browser (js) based clients

Tags: java, http, single-sign-on

Our system consists of multiple components stitched together. I am trying to replace existing component level authentication with an SSO (single sign on) solution for the complete system.

Each component has different interface - e.g. HTTP, HTTP/SOAP.

Also some clients are browser based and some are not (i.e. they use HTTP for signalling but are not browser/javascript clients).

Are there any Java SSO frameworks that fits this case?

Thanks a lot.

Ram

Comment: In what way can something send HTTP requests and not be a web client?

Comment: Sorry. What i meant was some clients are not "browser/javascript" based (but are java clients).

Comment: I'm sorry but your question is too open-ended. SSO is a concept, not something that can directly have some implementing framework. Check here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_single_sign-on_implementations . Which one?

Comment: Do not provide clarifications in comments. Instead, edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: Apache Shiro + SSO would seem a solution (no experience). Or maybe using LDAP for Windows Active Directory, doing all over Windows authentication if you are limited to a firm intern system.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a corporate environment, use Kerberos. Period.